# Notify when getting “no signal” on the LG Q6

Tags: android, notification

For several days now, the [LG Q6](https://www.gsmarena.com/lg_q6-8756.php) has made me angry when it suddenly stops detecting the SIM card. (once or twice a day)

I don't want to discuss the cause and possible solution. (Restart always helps)

The worst part is that the outage cannot be predicted.

Therefore, I want to ask if is there any app that would alert me to this, please? Either in the absence of a SIM card or on the loss of connection (of course, when the airplane mode isn't activated).

Comment: Not sure how well they work (especially as most of those apps having seen no update for quite a while), but maybe one of my collection for [Bad Signal Alert](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_cellsignal#group_404) can help? The one I used years ago is no longer available. Also see [What is Cell standby and how can I keep it from eating my battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/29447/16575) on our sister site which offers different solutions you might be interested in.

Comment: @Izzy Thank you, I installed [GSM Signal Monitor & SIM Card Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=paskov.biz.noservice&hl=cs&gl=US). Unfortunately, it cannot be tested, I have to wait until the problem occurs.

Comment: Sure. And as I know Murphy, now that you have a potential solution it might take a while until the problem occurs again (when you least expect it)… Just remember to keep us updated, please! And the app fits, be welcome to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the application [GSM Signal Monitor & SIM Card Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=paskov.biz.noservice&hl=en_US&gl=US)  works absolutely reliably. It didn't solve my problem, but it's a discussion about something else.